# Combine API results into single object in Powershell

Tags: powershell, pscustomobject

I have two API endpoints to hit and retrieve user info and write the data into a SQL table. The endpoint uses employee ID in the URL so I am looping through each user to grab their data. Endpoint #2 contains "custom fields" for the user. I am trying to combine the returns of both endpoints and write them as a single row for each user in the SQL table.

They return PSCustomObject as a hash table.
Endpoint # 1: cat6 NoteProperty string cat6=NONE

Endpoint #2: CustomText94 NoteProperty System.Management.Automation.PSCustomObject CustomText94=@{description=; value=}

```
function Export-Feed {

    Begin {
        $serverInstance = ""
        $database = ""
        $tableName = ""
        $employees = Get-Directory | Where-Object eestatus -eq A
    }

    Process {
        $result = $employees | ForEach-Object -Parallel {
            $params = @(
                'firstname',
                'middlename',
                'lastname',
                @{n='ADID';e={(Connect-Api -apiEndpoint "/api/v1/employee/$($_.eecode)/customfield").CustomText04.value}},
                'hire_date',
                'rehire_date',
                'position_title',
                'termination_date',
                'work_email',
                'employee_code',
                'clocksequencenumber',
                'department_code',
                'department_description',
                'employee_status',
                'supervisor_primary',
                'supervisor_primary_code',
                'supervisor_secondary',
                'supervisor_secondary_code',
                'supervisor_tertiary',
                'supervisor_tertiary_code',
                'supervisor_quaternary',
                'cat1',
                'cat1desc',
                'cat2',
                'cat2desc',
                'cat3',
                'cat3desc',
                'cat4',
                'cat4desc',
                'cat5',
                'cat5desc',
                'cat6',
                'cat6desc',
                'cat7',
                'cat7desc',
                'cat8',
                'cat8desc',
                'cat9',
                'cat9desc'
            )


            Connect-Api -apiEndpoint "/api/v1/employee/$($_.eecode)" | Select-Object $params

        }
    }
    
    End {
        $result | Out-File c:\temp\test.txt
        #Write-SqlTableData -DatabaseName $database -TableName $tableName -ServerInstance $serverInstance -SchemaName dbo -InputData $result -force 
    }
}
```

Comment: @mklement0 gotcha. New on Stack Overflow. I tried giving your answer credit. It said it did, but doesn't display it publicly due to the level of my account. Thanks for the help. I took your explanation of the [pscustomobject] and got a working result I am comfortable with.

Comment: Glad to hear it, @wimp777 - thanks for accepting. Your up-votes will become visible once you reach 15 reputation points.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To merge two custom objects (`[pscustomobject]` instances, which are *not* the same as hashtables), use the following technique:

```
# Two sample input objects.
$o1 = [pscustomobject] @{ one  = 1; two  = 2; three = 3 }
$o2 = [pscustomobject] @{ four = 4; five = 5; six   = 6 }

# Merge the two, by appending the properties of the 2nd to the 1st.
# Note: This assumes that there is no overlap between the property names.
foreach ($prop in $o2.psobject.Properties) {
  $o1.psobject.Properties.Add($prop, $true)
}

# $o1 now contains the union of both property sets; 
# Output it.
$o1 | Format-Table
```

The above yields:

```
one two three four five six
--- --- ----- ---- ---- ---
  1   2     3    4    5   6
```

The above relies on every object in PowerShell having a hidden `.psobject` property that provides reflection information about the object, notably the collection of all properties returned by the `.Properties` property.

PowerShell allows properties to be dynamically added to any property, which is feature of its [ETS (Extended Type System)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Types.ps1xml).
`[pscustomobject]` instances contain *only* such dynamic properties.
The [`.Add()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.management.automation.psmemberinfocollection-1.add#System_Management_Automation_PSMemberInfoCollection_1_Add__0_System_Boolean_) method allows adding a copy of another object's property to an object; the `$true` indicates that no validation need be performed, which speeds up the operation.